# Bootstrap 4 Text shrinks when collapsing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my website I have multiple sections where the title is at the top. Each section is a collapsable div.

Now, when the div collapses, the title is shrunk. This is a very annoying bug.

Here is my [website](http://david-lasry.com)

If you try to press a section, you would see the title is shrunk/expanded

Here is the markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ranga:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.3.0/ekko-lightbox.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>David Lasry</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container py-4">
        <header id="main-header">
            <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4">
                    <img src="img/profile.png" class="img-fluid">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                        <div id="name" class="px-3 pt-3 bg-dark text-white">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-6 py-2">
                                    <h1 class="display-4">David Lasry</h1>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-6">
                                    <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-around">
                                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/dudu.lasry" target="_blank">
                                            <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/dudulasry/" target="_blank">
                                            <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="https://github.com/david1542" target="_blank">
                                            <i class="fa fa-github"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="title" class="px-4 bg-black d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
                            <h4 class="display-4">
                                Android Developer/Full Stack Web Developer
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="actions" class="text-white text-center">
                            <div class="port-item bg-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#home">
                                <i class="fa fa-home d-block"></i>Home
                            </div>
                            <div class="port-item bg-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#resume">
                                <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap d-block"></i>Resume
                            </div>
                            <div class="port-item bg-warning" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#work">
                                <i class="fa fa-folder-open d-block"></i>Work
                            </div>
                            <div class="port-item bg-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#contact">
                                <i class="fa fa-envelope d-block"></i>Contact
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>

        <!-- Home -->
        <div id="home" class="collapse show">
            <div class="card card-body bg-primary text-white py-5 section-text">
                <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
                    <h1 id="owner" class="text-center">
                        Hi, I'm David. I design & build
                    </h1>
                    <h1 class="text-center">
                        <span class="typer" data-words="full stack web applications,landing pages,android applications" data-colors="#FF9E4C" data-delay="100"
                            data-deleteDelay="800"></span>
                        <span class="cursor" data-owner="#owner"></span>
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card card-body py-5">
                <h1>My Skills</h1>
                <p>
                    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos corrupti hic earum nihil quos consectetur.
                </p>
                <hr>
                <h4>HTML</h4>
                <div class="progress mb-3">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-success" style="width:100%"></div>
                </div>
                <h4>CSS</h4>
                <div class="progress mb-3">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-success" style="width:100%"></div>
                </div>
                <h4>JavaScript</h4>
                <div class="progress mb-3">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-success" style="width:90%"></div>
                </div>
                <h4>Java</h4>
                <div class="progress mb-3">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-success" style="width:80%"></div>
                </div>
                <h4>Groovy</h4>
                <div class="progress mb-3">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-success" style="width:70%"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Resume -->
        <div id="resume" class="collapse">
            <div class="card card-body bg-success text-white py-5 section-text">
                <h1>My Resume</h1>
                <p class="lead">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex, facere.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="card card-body py-5">
                <h3>Where have I worked?</h3>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi est, vitae praesentium magnam laborum officiis?
                </p>
                <div class="card-deck">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Devmasters</h4>
                            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum, quisquam.</p>
                            <p class="p-2 mb-3 bg-dark text-white">Position: Full Stack Developer</p>
                            <p class="p-2 mb-3 bg-dark text-white">Phone: (444) 444-4444</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <h6 class="text-muted">Dates: 2015 - 2017</h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Websites Pro</h4>
                            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum, quisquam.</p>
                            <p class="p-2 mb-3 bg-dark text-white">Position: Front End Developer</p>
                            <p class="p-2 mb-3 bg-dark text-white">Phone: (333) 333-3333</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <h6 class="text-muted">Dates: 2013 - 2015</h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title">123 Designs</h4>
                            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum, quisquam.</p>
                            <p class="p-2 mb-3 bg-dark text-white">Position: Designer</p>
                            <p class="p-2 mb-3 bg-dark text-white">Phone: (222) 222-4444</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <h6 class="text-muted">Dates: 2010 - 2013</h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Work -->
        <div id="work" class="collapse">
            <div class="card card-body bg-warning py-5 section-text">
                <h1>My Portfolio</h1>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe, voluptates.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="card card-body py-5">
                <h3>What have I built?</h3>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda necessitatibus explicabo officiis dolore.
                </p>
                <div class="row no-gutters">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <a href="https://picsum.photos/1200/768/?image=788" data-toggle="lightbox">
                            <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/?image=788" class="img-fluid">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <a href="https://picsum.photos/1200/768/?image=789" data-toggle="lightbox">
                            <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/?image=789" class="img-fluid">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <a href="https://picsum.photos/1200/768/?image=790" data-toggle="lightbox">
                            <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/?image=790" class="img-fluid">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <a href="https://picsum.photos/1200/768/?image=791" data-toggle="lightbox">
                            <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/?image=791" class="img-fluid">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row no-gutters">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <a href="https://picsum.photos/1200/768/?image=796" data-toggle="lightbox">
                            <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/?image=796" class="img-fluid">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <a href="https://picsum.photos/1200/768/?image=793" data-toggle="lightbox">
                            <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/?image=793" class="img-fluid">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <a href="https://picsum.photos/1200/768/?image=794" data-toggle="lightbox">
                            <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/?image=794" class="img-fluid">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <a href="https://picsum.photos/1200/768/?image=795" data-toggle="lightbox">
                            <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/?image=795" class="img-fluid">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Contact -->
        <div id="contact" class="collapse">
            <div class="card card-body bg-danger text-white py-5 section-text">
                <h1>Contact</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card card-body py-5 h3">
                <h3>Get in touch</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque.</p>
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <span class="input-group-addon bg-danger text-white">
                                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                            </span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control bg-dark text-white" placeholder="Name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <span class="input-group-addon bg-danger text-white">
                                <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                            </span>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control bg-dark text-white" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <span class="input-group-addon bg-danger text-white">
                                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                            </span>
                            <textarea class="form-control bg-dark text-white" placeholder="Message" rows="5"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-lg">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer id="main-footer" class="p-5 bg-dark text-white">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-light">
                        <i class="fa fa-cloud"></i>
                        Download Resume
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/typer.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.3.0/ekko-lightbox.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(".port-item").click(function () {
            $(".collapse").collapse("hide");
        });

        $(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="lightbox"]', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).ekkoLightbox();
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

And here is my css file:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Ranga', cursive;
    background: #2980b9 url('https://static.tumblr.com/03fbbc566b081016810402488936fbae/pqpk3dn/MRSmlzpj3/tumblr_static_bg3.png') repeat 0 0;
    -webkit-animation: 10s linear 0s normal none infinite animate;
    -moz-animation: 10s linear 0s normal none infinite animate;
    -ms-animation: 10s linear 0s normal none infinite animate;
    -o-animation: 10s linear 0s normal none infinite animate;
    animation: 10s linear 0s normal none infinite animate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate {
    from {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    to {
        background-position: 500px 0;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes animate {
    from {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    to {
        background-position: 500px 0;
    }
}

@-ms-keyframes animate {
    from {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    to {
        background-position: 500px 0;
    }
}

@-o-keyframes animate {
    from {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    to {
        background-position: 500px 0;
    }
}

@keyframes animate {
    from {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    to {
        background-position: 500px 0;
    }
}

.collapse {
    .card.section-text {
        border: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        h1 {
            font-size: 50px !important;           
        }
    }
}

#main-header {
    .row.no-gutters {
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 320px;
        .col-lg-3.col-md-4 {
            min-height: 100%;
            img {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        }
        .col-lg-9.col-md-8 {
            .d-flex {
                height: 100%;
                #name {
                    flex-basis: 35%;
                    h1 {
                        padding-left: 30px;
                        font-size: 70px;
                        font-weight: 400;
                    }
                    .d-flex.flex-row {
                        flex: 1 0 40%;
                        a {
                            text-decoration: none;
                            color: white;
                            .fa {
                                font-size: 30px;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                #title {
                    flex-basis: 30%;
                    background: black;
                    color: white;
                    padding: 0;
                    .display-4 {
                        font-size: 30px;
                    }
                }
                #actions {
                    display: flex;
                    flex-basis: 35%;
                    flex-direction: row;
                    flex-wrap: wrap;
                    width: 100%;
                    .port-item {
                        display: flex;
                        flex-direction: column;
                        justify-content: center;
                        flex-basis: 25%;
                        border: none;
                        font-size: 20px;
                        .fa {
                            font-size: 2em;
                        }
                    }
                    .port-item:hover {
                        cursor: pointer;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    #main-header {
        .row {
            .col-lg-9.col-md-8 {
                #name {
                    .row {
                        .col-lg-7.col-md-6 {
                            h1 {
                                font-size: 30px;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@media (max-width: 770px) {
    #main-header {
        .row.no-gutters {
            .col-lg-9.col-md-8 {
                #name {
                    .row {
                        .col-lg-7.col-md-6 {
                            h1 {
                                text-align: center;
                                font-size: 40px;
                                margin-bottom: 10px;
                                padding: 0;
                            }
                        }
                        .col-lg-5.col-md-6 {
                            .d-flex {
                                margin-bottom: 20px;
                                .fa {
                                    font-size: 30px;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                #actions {
                    .port-item {
                        padding: 40px 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
    #main-header {
        .row.no-gutters {
            .col-lg-9.col-md-8 {
                .d-flex {
                    #actions {
                        .port-item {
                            font-size: 3.5vw;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#main-footer {
    .btn.btn-outline-light {
        transition: color 0.3s;
    }
    .btn.btn-outline-light:hover {
        color: black;
    }
}

@media(min-width: 1199px) {
    #actions {
        .port-item {
            padding: 3em !important;
        }
    }
}
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are applying a style to `h1` using the `collapse` class and this class appear/disappear when you change section so your style are removed during the transition. You need to get rid of this class:

Instead of this:

```
.collapse .card.section-text h1 {
    font-size: 50px!important;
}
```

Simply use this:

```
.card.section-text h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

There is also another element that have the same issue

So you need to change this:

```
.collapse .card.section-text {
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

To simply this:

```
.card.section-text {
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```